# If-else logic to set value of dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have data in a dataframe `(df)` that resembles the structure below

| ID | Sessions |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 400 |
| 5678 | 200 |
| 9101112 | 199 |
| 13141516 | 0 |

I want to create a new column `(new_col`) in the dataframe that ranks each example per Session value, except I want to make sure 0 Sessions are not considered in the rank/zeroed out.

I have attempted applying the lambda below, but this not correct:

```
df['new_col'] = df['Sessions'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x == 0 else df['Sessions'].rank(ascending=True, pct=True))
```

sample desired output

| ID | Sessions | new_col |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 400 | 1.000000 |
| 5678 | 200 | 0.999987 |
| 9101112 | 199 | 0.999974 |
| 13141516 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: could you add a few more lines of example data? what do you mean by 'each example per session value'? is that for each ID? An expected output would be useful

Comment: @EmiOB just added to my original post - the rank function is working for me (`df['Sessions'].rank(ascending=True, pct=True)`) I just want to make sure if there are 0 sessions the new_col value is 0 - right now thats not happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this ? :

```
df['new_col'] = df.loc[df.Sessions > 0, 'Sessions'].rank(ascending=True, pct=True)
```

or

```
df['new_col'] = df['Sessions'].replace(0, np.NaN).rank(pct=True,).fillna(0)
```

Comment: I used second option and had to modify because my 0s were actually a str :\. `testx_df['Sessions'].replace('0', np.NaN).rank(ascending=True, pct=True).fillna(0)` Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you want a secure slicing, assign is your friend. Try this.

```
df.assign(newcol=lambda d: (
    d["Sessions"] # grab the series
    .replace(0, np.NaN) # replace the 0s with NaNs
    .rank(pct=True, ) # rank as percentages
    .fillna(0) # fill zeros back in.
   )
)
```

Also, this way you will be able to neatly wrap this pipe in a function.

Comment: This looks really cool but when I test it out I keep getting the error - I think its the way I am trying to apply it within my code `testx_df['new_col'] = testx_df.assign(new_col=lambda d: (d["Sessions"].replace(0, np.NaN).rank(pct=True, ).fillna(0)))`

Comment: @hansolo. Yes. the `df.assign(..)` adds the new column and returns the entire dataframe in place. So, you don't need the `df['new_col'] = ` part, simply copy paste the snippet above.